# What is the fastest way to change Python environment?

Tags: python, external-calls, external-language-cell

We can see all registered Python environments through `FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]`.

But the user interface will use the last registered one.

How to use a different Python environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**env test_1**

```
env=StartExternalSession[{"Python","Executable"->"C:\\miniconda3\\envs\\test_1\\python.exe"}]

ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Python"] = env
```

[image]

> C:\miniconda3\envs\test_1\python.exe

**env test_2** in the same session

```
env=StartExternalSession[{"Python","Executable"->"C:\\miniconda3\\envs\\test_2\\python.exe"}]

ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Python"] = env
```

[image]

> C:\miniconda3\envs\test_2\python.exe